# ImportError: No module named flask error when run on apache server

Tags: python, apache, flask

The flask server works perfectly when using flask run, but it fails to work when configured in apache2 and gives the following errors:

```
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.402862 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091] mod_wsgi (pid=24929): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.403091 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091] mod_wsgi (pid=24929): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.403200 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.403273 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.403441 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091]     from app import app as application
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.403448 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/app.py", line 2, in <module>
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.403464 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091]     from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, session, g
[Wed Jul 08 13:43:43.403545 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24929:tid 140372047017728] [client 10.200.180.125:53091] ImportError: No module named flask
```

The flask package is installed and actually without apache2, `flask run` works perfectly fine.

```
root@jsd-user-management:~# pip freeze
...
Flask==1.1.2
...
```

flaskapp.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation")


from app  import app as application
application.secret_key = 'omar'
```

and finally, this is the flaskApp.conf file

```
WSGIRestrictStdout Off
WSGIScriptReloading On
<VirtualHost *:80>

                ServerName user-management.x.com
                ServerAdmin o.a@x.com
                #WSGIProcessGroup app
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/>
                        Allowoverride None
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/static/>
                        AllowOverride None
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>

                Alias /templates /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/templates
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/customer-account-automation/templates/>
                        AllowOverride None
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the tree to see the location of the files.

```
root@jsd-user-management:/var/www# tree
.
├── FlaskApp
│   ├── customer-account-automation
│   │   ├── Pipfile
│   │   ├── Pipfile.lock
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── app.py
│   │   ├── customerAccountMgmt.py
│   │   ├── flaskapp.wsgi
│   │   ├── get-pip.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── app.js
│   │   │   ├── bulma.min.css
│   │   │   ├── highlight.min.css
│   │   │   ├── highlight.min.js
│   │   │   └── styles.css
│   │   └── templates
│   │       ├── 404.html
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── change_password.html
│   │       ├── create_user.html
│   │       ├── deactivate_user.html
│   │       └── login.html
│   └── flaskapp.wsgi
└── html
```

Comment: Is the interpreter that you've installed flask to the same one as specified in your `flaskapp.wsgi`? `/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: yes it's the same ```flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.1.2)```

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip -V` and `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip freeze | grep -i flask`?

Comment: `pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`


and `Flask==1.1.2`

Comment: Apache will create a new user i guess.. And you had installed Flask for root user.. Apache user don't have permission for flask.